# Sign of the special value at s=0 of Hecke L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $L/K$ be an abelian extension of number fields with Galois group $G$ and let $\chi : G \to \{\pm 1\}$ denote a real linear character of $G$. Denote $L(\chi,s)$ the Artin L-function associated to $\chi$, $n=\mathrm{ord}_{s=0} L(\chi,s)$ and
$$
L^\ast(\chi,0)=\lim_{s\to 0} L(\chi,s)s^{-n}
$$
its special value at $s=0$. It is known this L-functions is also the L-function associated to a Hecke character. My question is: what are the conjectures and results regarding the sign of $L^\ast(\chi,0)$ ? My current work has gotten me to conjecture that it is $-1$ for the trivial character and $1$ otherwise, and I wonder if this is something known or conjectured.

Comment: Why should it be a real number?

Comment: Is your conjecture 1 for trivial character or -1 for trivial character?

Comment: Are you asking for the factor of absolute value 1 in its polar decomposition? Unless $\chi$ is real-valued, that factor is unlikely to be $\pm 1$.

Comment: @DavidFarmer It is -1 for the trivial character, I have edited my post.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I was looking at Artin L-functions of rational representations initially, and wanted to reduce to Hecke L-functions by Artin induction. But I overlooked that the special value is then not necessarily a real number indeed.

Comment: In general, these signs (or arguments) will be controlled by the root numbers of the $L$-function, which are analogue to Gauss sums and can be quite difficult to determine (one may think of the problem of determining the sign of the classical quadratic Gauss sum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\chi$ is real-valued, then the question makes sense. Using the functional equation, it reduces to computing the sign of the non-zero real number $L(\chi, 1)$ if $\chi$ is non-trivial, or the residue of $L(\chi, s) = \zeta_K(s)$ at $s = 1$ if $\chi$ is trivial. In either case, $L(\chi, s)$ tends to $+1$ for $s$ large and real, and it cannot vanish on $Re(s) > 1$, so $L(\chi, 1+\epsilon) > 0$ for all positive $\epsilon$. This shows that $L(\chi, 1) > 0$ for $\chi \ne 1$, and that $Res_{s=1} \zeta_K(s) < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide a slightly different proof to that of David Loeffler, using only that $\zeta_K^\ast(0)<0$ for any number field $K$. A real valued linear character factors through $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, corresponding to a quadratic extension $L/K$, so we can suppose that $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ; denoting $\chi$ its non trivial character we have the relation $\mathrm{ind}~1=1+\chi$ thus $$L^\ast(\chi,0)=\frac{\zeta^\ast_L(0)}{\zeta^\ast_K(0)}>0$$